# Read 2 Files into map characters

Tags: java, file, compare, maps

The task is: First file is with random words and the second has the letters in the alphabet and the values.
I have to read this two files into map data structure and for each word in the other file I have to print out their point value:

`enter code here
``

```
static void readMap(String path, HashMap<String,Object> set) {
    `try {
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
                while(in.readLine() != null) {
                    String line = in.readLine();
                    set.put(line,1);
                }
                in.close();
            } catch(FileNotFoundException x) {
                System.out.println(x.getMessage());
            } catch(IOException y) {
                System.out.println(y.getMessage());
            }
        }
```

This is what I have. But I have no Idea how I could compare these two files...
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please explain this more clearly: "First file is with random words and the second has the letters in the alphabet and the values.", or give sample input and output

Comment: The first file is this:
qabalah
qabalahs
qabalas                                                                                                                                                                                                                    second file:            a;1
b;3
c;3
d;2
e;1
f;4
g;2
h;4
i;1
j;8
k;5
l;1
m;3
n;1
o;1
p;3
q;10
r;1
s;1
t;1
u;1
v;4
w;4
x;8
y;4
z;10                                                                                                           so it should be like a scrabble game. I have to give out the value for the words from the first file

Comment: Ok and what is the "point value"  ? for "abc" would it be "133" or do you add the numbers, so "7" ? Also, you should say if this is homework

Comment: it would be 7. Ah sorry, this a project I have to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things you need to do:

1. Read letters file, add each key,value pair (letter, number value) to a map.
2. Read random words file, iterate over each letter in each word, retrieve it's integer value (from the map) and add it to the sum

I've provided some code but you will need to implement some of it yourself.

`

```
HashMap<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("letters.txt"));
while(in.readLine() != null) {
    String line = in.readLine();
    //TODO you need to split the string by ';' and get the char and int
    char c = ...
    int x = ...
    set.put(c,x);
}


BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("random_words.txt"));
while(in.readLine() != null) {
    String line = in.readLine();
    int total = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++)
    {
        char c = line.charAt(i);
        //TODO get integer value from map, add it to the total, and print it after the loop
        int value = ...
        total += value;
    }
    System.out.println("value for word " + line + " is " + total);
}
```

Comment: I'm happy to help. If this answer solves your problem, please accept it.

Comment: oh I have another question. I printed under this comment, because the output is there better